# Rails: Carrierwave crop and fill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

How do I get an image to show up with the dimensions 1030x150 with out looking stretched?

I have tried to use crop and fill with carrierwave but it doesn't seem to be working. Currently the image is showing up as one large square image but I would like to crop the image so the center of it is showing up as a long banner on the top of the page.

Thanks!

Here is my image uploader code:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [32, 32]
  end

  version :preview do
    process :resize_to_fit => [256, 256]
  end

  version :full do
    process :resize_to_fill => [1030, 150]
         process crop: '1030x150+0+0'
  end


  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end


  def crop(geometry)
    manipulate! do |img|      
      img.crop(geometry)
      img
    end    
  end


end
```

Show page where the banner will show up in the header div:

```
<div id="products_div">
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
 <%= image_tag @stone.image.full.url %>
    <h1><%= @stone.name %></h1> 
</div>


       <% @stone.products.each do |product| %>
         <div class="center-block">

        <div class="col-lg-3">
         <div class = "thumbnail row">
            <%= link_to product do %>

                  <%= image_tag product.image.preview.url, :size => "224.98x178.66" %>

            <% end %>
           <p><%= product.name[0..25] + "..." %></p>
        <p><%= number_to_currency(product.price, :unit => '$') %></p>
         </div>
          </div>
          </div>
       <% end %>
   </div>

</div>

<% if current_admin %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stone_path(@stone) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', admin_stones_path %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you: https://github.com/imgix/imgix-rails. 
It works for me.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.